# Dynamic Data asp.net Foreign key relationship in DropdownList, how to customise?

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-sql, asp.net-dynamic-data

I'm working on `Asp.Net Dynamic Data project with linq to sql`.

I've created a database that has `one to one relationship` between two tables specified using a foreign key.

i.e. I have a table `Employee` and table `Department`

```
Employee table
empid empname address departmentId 

Department table
departmentId departmentname
```

now `Student` table takes an `departmentId` as a `foreign key`

when I navigated to `/Insert.aspx` that it would display the a list of `department_name` in a dropdown list.

It does this - but it shows all the `department_name` into dropdownlist

> How and where I could write linq query so that i can customize those department_name values

If suppose I want to only populate `computers` as a department_name in that dropdownlist
how could I achieve this ?

Code:
In FieldTemplate folder `ForeignKey_Edit.ascx.cs`

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (DropDownList1.Items.Count == 0)
        {
            if (Mode == DataBoundControlMode.Insert || !Column.IsRequired)
            {
                DropDownList1.Items.Add(new ListItem("[Not Set]", ""));
            }
            PopulateListControl(DropDownList1);
        }

        SetUpValidator(RequiredFieldValidator1);
        SetUpValidator(DynamicValidator1);
    }
```

data dynamics is populating dropdownlist internally.

here before or after this statement `PopulateListControl(DropDownList1);`

what should I code so that i can populate only specific value..?

Comment: what have u done so far? how u populated ur dropdownlist as of now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `PopulateListControl(DropDownList1);`
try something like this

```
        if (ForeignKeyColumn.ParentTable.Name == "Departments")
        {
            List<Department> departments = // code to grab the correct Departments

            foreach (Department d in departments)
            {
                DropDownList1.Items.Add(new ListItem(d.Name, d.Id.ToString()));
            }
        }
```